# best practice for similar linked tasks?

Tags: linux, scripting

I'm setting up a server for a small office, that is accessable from the internet. Since our ISP has a transparent proxy, most dynamic dns services fail, other than dyndns (who isn't our provider) so we use a script to set it manually- it connects to dyndns, fetches a web page with the info, strips the ip address out, and sets the ip address for a single domain via a web request to our actual dns provider. This whole process is run once an hour by crontab

If i wanted to extend this to more than one hostname, would it be a better idea to have one script running per hostname (ie, single script for obtaining the ip address, and one per hostname) or to have a single monolithic task for the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any one answer to this. Having multiple scripts will make it easier to turn it off on a hostname-by-hostname basis. On the other hand it will somewhat increase the maintenance overhead by giving you more places to look. Personally I would do it all in one script unless there was a really compelling reason not.

Comment: i went for a single script for now, though its designed so that i could easily split off the tasks